# Why won't this @font-face work in IE8?

Tags: font-face

I've tried so many different variations but none of this will work in IE:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Friday';
    src: url(../fonts/callie.eot);
    src: local('☺'), url(../fonts/callie.otf) format('opentype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting IE 6-8 properties (and a few more).

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Friday';
    src: url('callie.eot');                                    /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('callie.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('callie.woff') format('woff'),                    /* Modern Browsers */
         url('callie.ttf')  format('truetype'),                /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url('callie.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');          /* Legacy iOS */
    }
```

Source: http://www.fontspring.com/blog/further-hardening-of-the-bulletproof-syntax

You can also generate new files and valid CSS with [Font Squirrel Generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator)

And Paul Irish has published about this matter [here](http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/)

Comment: Hmm, for some reason that isn't working either. Nothing seems to get through to it. How anybody can actually ever use IE is beyond me!

Comment: I've edited with a new alternative and a place where get more info.